# Rust how to urlencode a string with byte parameters?

Tags: encoding, rust

I have some parameters like so:

```
{'peer_id': '-PC0001-781232119400', 'port': 6889, 'event': 'started', 'compact': 1, 'left': 2097152000, 'uploaded': 0, 'info_hash': b'\xd5@\xfcH\xeb\x12\xf2\x831c\xee\xd6B\x1dD\x9d\xd8\xf1\xce\x1f', 'downloaded': 0}
```

I'd like to have it all urlencoded into a string like so:

```
my_url?peer_id=-PC0001-781232119400&port=6889&event=started&compact=1&left=1&uploaded=0&info_hash=%D5%40%FCH%EB%12%F2%831c%EE%D6B%1DD%9D%D8%F1%CE%1F&downloaded=0"
```

I've played around with urlcode and come up with this:

```
extern crate url;
use url::form_urlencoded;

fn main() {

    let encoded: String = form_urlencoded::Serializer::new(String::new())
        .append_pair("foo", "bar & baz")
        .append_pair("saison", "Été+hiver")
        .finish();

    println!("{:?}", encoded);
}
```

Problem is, `apprend_pair` takes in a pair of `&'str` - it doesn't take in bytes...I'm not sure how to accomplish my goal.

In python, I'd simply use the builtin `from urllib.parse import urlencode`
 and do `urlencode(params)`

Answer (score 2):

It's a bit of a hack, but you can override how values are encoded through a closure, and thus, you'll be able to sneak in binary values that way. I make use of `"!"` to indicate where to substitute the binary values in my example below, but you could really use anything:

```
fn main() {
    let binary = vec![0, 1, 2, 3];

    let encoded = form_urlencoded::Serializer::new(String::new())
        .append_pair("foo", "bar & baz")
        .append_pair("saison", "Été+hiver")
        .encoding_override(Some(&|input| {
            if input != "!" {
                // Return the actual value ("info_hash", in this particular case)
                Cow::Borrowed(input.as_bytes())
            } else {
                // When "!" is seen, return the binary data instead
                Cow::Owned(binary.clone())
            }
        }))
        .append_pair("info_hash", "!")
        .finish();

    println!("{:?}", encoded);
}
```

This outputs

> "foo=bar+%26+baz&saison=%C3%89t%C3%A9%2Bhiver&info_hash=%00%01%02%03"

You can try it out here: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=805d80ebbc98909fa32177030102ba12